# Correct typing for generic Database abstraction

Tags: typescript

So I'm writing a backend which relies on DynamoDB, and as part of that I'm writing a simple set of functions over the top of the node SDK to make my code easier to test. Where one of those functions returns data, I'd like to be able to assign the value to typed objects without either returning `any` or having to typecast. I've tried a generic parameter like this:

```js
export const getAll = async<T extends Record<string, unknown>[]> (
  table: string
): Promise<T> => {
  const params = {
    TableName: table,
  };
  const result = await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
  return result.Items ?? [];
};
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error message

> Type 'ItemList' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, unknown>'

Now I guess I kind of understand why this doesn't work, because there is no way of knowing when writing the function what T is, therefore its impossible to ensure that there will be a relationship between what the function actually returns and the type parameter.

I've tried typing it as a `record` type:

```js
type Customer = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
}

export const getAll = async (
  table: string
): Promise<Record<string, unknown>[]>> => {
  const params = {
    TableName: table,
  };
  const result = await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
  return result.Items ?? [];
};
```

But now when I try to assign it to a variable of type `Customer`, I get the following error message:

> Type 'Record<string, unknown>[]' is not assignable to type 'Customer': Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties of type 'Customer': id, name

At the present time, I'm doing the latter, but I'm having to do a rather nasty `as unknown as Customer[]` cast to get it to work. I'm sure that this isn't correct so I'd really appreciate some advice on how to correctly type this.

Comment: You are saying to TS that you expect `Promise<T>` but in same time you are trying to return just empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need any runtime type checking then you are probably best off just casting the return type from DynamoDB as `T[]` using something like this:

```
import { DynamoDB } from "aws-sdk";
const dynamoDb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

type Customer = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

export const getAll = async <T>(table: string): Promise<T[]> => {
  const params = { TableName: table };
  const result = await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
  return result.Items as T[] ?? [];
};

const doIt = async () => {
  const customers: Customer[] = await getAll<Customer>("my-customer-id");
  // Do something with your customers
};
```